# Grails 3 Database Migration Plugin - Task 'dbmGenerateChangelog' not found

Tags: liquibase, grails-3.0

Recently I tried to run Database Migration Plugin with Grails 3.0.11. The problem is when I run `$grails dbm-generate-gorm-changelog changelog.groovy` or `$grails dbm-generate-changelog changelog.groovy` I get the following error:

```
Error occurred running Grails CLI: Task 'dbmGenerateChangelog' not found in root project
```

I belive it's a simple problem. What am I missing? How can I make it work?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are missing the dependency from the buildscript -block on your build.gradle file. The commands has been changed to gradle tasks.

https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-database-migration

Comment: Yep, that was it. Had to add `classpath "org.grails.plugins:database-migration:2.0.0.RC1"` in my buildscript block under dependencies. Thanks for advaice!